# How to create a model factory with foreign key laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, faker

I have a model factory as:

**QuestionFactory.php:**

```
$factory->define(App\Question::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'question' => $faker->text($maxNbChars = 150),
        'subject_id' => $faker->randomElement(App\Subject::pluck('id')->toArray()),
        'sbj_type_id' => $faker->randomElement(App\SbjType::pluck('id')->toArray())
    ];
});
```

but the above code also fetches the other subject type here`sbj_type_id` is linked to `sbj_type` table and then there's also a field that which a `sbj_type` relates, **.e.g.**, I have 2 subjects and 4 sub type so I have 2 type linked to 1 subject and other 2 relates to second subject so I need to fetch according to subject_id also, I have done this

```
'sbj_type_id' => $faker->randomElement(App\SbjType::where('subject_id', App\Subject::inRandomOrder()->value('id'))->pluck('id')->toArray())
```

**All I need to fetch `sbj_type` according to `subject_id`**

Answer (score 2):

Use the query builder's `inRandomOrder` paired with the `value` method to get a random ID directly out of the database:

```php
App\Subject::inRandomOrder()->value('id')
```

---

To put that into your factory, it'd look like this:

```php
$factory->define(App\Question::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'question' => $faker->text($maxNbChars = 150),
        'subject_id' => App\Subject::inRandomOrder()->value('id'),
        'sbj_type_id' => App\SbjType::inRandomOrder()->value('id'),
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, I used:

```
$subject = App\Subject::inRandomOrder()->value('id');
return [
    'question' => $faker->text($maxNbChars = 150),
    'subject_id' => $subject,
    'sbj_type_id' => App\SbjType::where('subject_id', $subject)->inRandomOrder()->value('id'),
]
```

First of all I get `subject_id` from database and stored it into a variable `$subject` after that in faker code I used that variable in the condition so that's it I solved my problem, Thanks to @JosephSilber